# AjaxToolkit AsyncFileUpload needs ViewStateMode enabled, how to avoid?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, viewstate, asyncfileupload

I know this is rather a trivial question but anyhow I want to know if it is solvable.

I have an ASP.NET webform page with a nested masterpage and JavaScript includes. I make extensive use of jQuery and Ajax calls. Once a page is loaded, all communication with the server is done with Ajax calls, so I don't need ViewState enabled, and this is resulting in a reduced HTML output code.

I now have to implement a page where a user can upload a file. So I used the AsyncFileUpload control of AjaxToolkitFileUpload. Once a file is uploaded, I do a Ajax call to the server to request the filename.

It all works fine but I noticed that FireBug found 10 errors per file upload between the OnClientUploadStarted and the OnClientUploadComplete events. The file is uploaded properly and the events on the client side are working too. But I can't ignore the fact that there are errors thrown so I went looking for the problem.

I rebuild the page piece by piece and I found out that this control needs the Viewstate enabled.
However with *viewstate=disabled* in the page directive the file size is 76.6kb, and with *viewstate=enabled* the size is 99.2kb.

Again, I know it is trivial and will not affect performance on the site, but it is a nice to know. 
- Why does this control needs the viewstate? (I suppose because it actually post the file to a iFrame or something like that?)
- How can I reduce the viewstate and let this control still work properly?

Answer (score 0):

For reducing view state and having this one control work properly, you can use leave view state enabled on your page and set the [ViewStateMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstatemode.aspx) to Disabled for the page and then set the ViewStateMode to Enabled for the one control that needs view state.  For all other controls they should inherit the setting of the parent by default.